GraphView don't show anything on IOS in release mode in Flutter
I’m facing an issue with the GraphView library. During development, everything works well—I can test and see the graph generated just fine. However, when I try to publish it to my iPhone using TestFlight, the graph only shows a blank screen.is there any way to fix this issue?
  final Graph graph = Graph()..isTree = true;

  BuchheimWalkerConfiguration builder = BuchheimWalkerConfiguration(); 



var usableDevices = widget.devices.where((device) => device.deviceType != 0).map((device) => Node.Id(device.address)).toList();
    fillRouters();
    for (var router in routerNodes) {
      graph.addEdge(usableDevices.firstWhere((node) => (node.key!.value as int?) == router.parent),
          usableDevices.firstWhere((node) => (node.key!.value as int?) == router.address));
    }
    addEdges(usableDevices);

    builder
      ..siblingSeparation = (30)
      ..levelSeparation = (80)
      ..subtreeSeparation = (30)
      ..orientation = (BuchheimWalkerConfiguration.ORIENTATION_TOP_BOTTOM);

I test it with same code on ios and android simulator and physical phone and there is no problem but when publish it over Testflight I face with this problem that graph shows empty screen is there anyone know what's go wrong?
